# Troubleshoot Python script to update Dynamic DNS with NameCheap (Script from Help Ubuntu)

Tags: python, scripts, dns

First off, please help me with the question, dont offer me options like DDClient~! Not to be rude, but lots of people offer workarounds, Id like to use this method and im just having a bit of trouble getting it going.

The script is from [Help Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DynamicDNS#Namecheap_.26_Python)

This is the original Snippit that relates to what I want to do

Namecheap & Python

You can update with namecheap and python with the following script. Use your prefered editor and create the file /home/USERNAME/update_dns

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import urllib2

urllib2.urlopen("http://dynamicdns.park-your-domain.com/update?host=%s&domain=%s&password=%s" % ("@", "YOURDOMAIN", "YOURPASSWORD"))
```

Enter into the terminal

crontab -e
and add the following line

```
* */1 * * * python /home/USERNAME/update_dns
```

This will update every hour.

All I subbed was YOURDOMAIN and YOURPASSWORD, not sure if i was supposed to touch the link but i get this error

```
./update_dns: line 2: import: command not found
./update_dns: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `"http://dynamicdns.park-your-domain.com/update?host=%s&domain=%s&password=%          s"'
./update_dns: line 4: `urllib2.urlopen("http://dynamicdns.park-your-domain.com/update?host=%s&domain=%s&password=%s" % ("@", REMOVED))'
```

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 x64 Always Updated

Answer (score 1):

I needed to add

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

To the top of the Script and remove python from crontab entry

Comment: Yeah, the first line of the file is supposed to be a comment of the shell or interpreter to run the script.  It didn't find one, so it tried to just use sh.  Then when sh ran it didn't know what to do with the file.  I see now that your cron entry was supposed to use python to invoke the file, so I don't know why it didn't work.

Comment: OHHH!! I tried to just run the script to test it!, thats why!, there is no harm in using the line of code I used even tho it says python in the cron is there? or should i remove python from the cron job and just have it call the script now that it works? Or remove the line of code and be more patient! lol, the thing is i set up my A-record with a loopback IP so i could test the script lol, so I was just doing ./update_dns

Comment: I just read through some examples in crontab, perhaps where it says python it is actually using that as the user name?  Oh, you mean that output wasn't from the cron job?  Yeah, you should have tried python ./update_dns.... to test it.

Comment: thats correct, lol, Learning Curve ;)

Comment: think i can just leave it as is?

Comment: Yeah, it should be fine.

Comment: actually I removed that line and got mail about errors, so I removed pyhton from crontab and kept the line in the code!